# Could not access "synaptics sensors" device error on ubuntu 20.04 focal fosa

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I was trying to register my fingerprint on my Lenovo Thinkpad P43s and while in this process i got this error: `GDbus.Error:net.reativated.Fprint.error.internal: Open failed with error: The driver encountred a protocol error with the device.`

How do i fix this error?

Answer (score 8):

I got it working on my Thinkpad X395 by following this: [P43s - Working fingerprint reader on Linux : thinkpad](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/e90cgp/p43s_working_fingerprint_reader_on_linux/)

First, uninstall older version of `fwupd`:

```
sudo apt-get remove fwupd
```

Then, install 1.4.1 version of `fwupd` in Ubunutu Software manager.

Then download firmware and config files from here:

1. [LVFS: Prometheus Fingerprint Reader](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/com.synaptics.prometheus.firmware)
2. [LVFS: Prometheus Fingerprint Reader Configuration](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/com.synaptics.prometheus.config)

Install them with:

```
fwupdmgr install 3b5102b3430329a10a3636b4a594fc3dd2bfdc09-Synaptics-Prometheus-10.02.3110269.cab
fwupdmgr install cbe7b45a2591e9d149e00cd4bbf0ccbe5bb95da7-Synaptics-Prometheus_Config-0021.cab
```

The second file was an older version in my case, so you might not need to install it.

Then, try again in Settings→User→Fingerprint Login.

Comment: `No supported devices found` on fwupdmgr install

Answer (score 2):

I got it working on Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad T490s by installing gnome-firmware and using that to install a newer version on the Prometheus Fingerprint reader (upgraded to version 10.01.3158804) and Prometheus IOTA Config (upgraded to version 0021). I did not install a newer version of fwupd (installed version is 1.3.9-4ubuntu0.1)

I did not need to reboot; once the firmware upgrade was complete, I could enable fingerprint login and register a fingerprint.

Comment: Could you maybe explain _how_ you performed those tasks? Show some commands I can copy? :-)

Comment: @MoRe I'm not the OP, but this worked for me. `sudo apt-get install gnome-firmware`, then run `gnome-firmware` and upgrade all the firmware components to latest, reboot, run `gnome-firmware` again and install any new options. By this point I had a working fingerprint reader.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work on my X1 yoga 5th gen (with a 06cb:00bd Synaptics reader) by enabling the lvfs-testing channel for fwupdmgr

UPDATE: actually the `fwupdmgr enable-remote lvfs-testing` command might not be needed anymore.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
#fwupdmgr enable-remote lvfs-testing
fwupdmgr update
```

then you can enroll the fingers under the ubuntu user settings and test with

```
 fprintd-verify
```

Comment: I get ```failed to claim device: Open failed with error: Device 06cb:00bd is already open```

Answer (score 0):

On my HP Probook 435 works also updating FW with newer fwupd (tested on >1.5, installed via snap, apt provide only old versions)

so like this

```
  fwupdmgr enable-remote lvfs-testing
  fwupdmgr refresh --force
  fwupdmgr update
  fwupdmgr disable-remote lvfs-testing
```