# Fingerprint reader not working | Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: drivers, hp

I'm looking for some insight on getting my fingerprint reader to work.

I have an HP Envy Model 13-aq0500od dual boot set up with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. The fingerprint reader works just fine with Windows 10 so I know it is operational.

I have googled a few things and one thread said to [update the firmware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231967/could-not-access-synaptics-sensors-device-error-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fosa) after I searched for the initial error message I received. However I'm pretty sure the fingerprint reader in the Lenovo described in that thread uses different firmware so I don't think that exact solution would work. This official [HP thread](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Fingerprint-drivers-on-linux/td-p/8129841) states that HP does not provide support for Linux distros but the reader is a Synaptics device so I feel like it should have a Linux driver and/or firmware package.

Comment: According to https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=20185e7b49, the fingerprint reader is not supported at least until kernel 5.15

Comment: Oh darn.

Thanks for sharing, I didn't even know linux-hardawre.org was a thing. I am a novice with Linux, but this is a helpful resource.